# Сложение результатов вычисления на js

Tags: javascript

Делаю калькулятор для подбора оборудования под аренду, получаю и складываю поля , но далее надо посчитать результат поля res1 и res2 и т.д, не понимаю как реализовать это.

```js
function add(res0) {
  var plar = parseInt(document.getElementById('plar').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);
  var arpl = parseInt(document.getElementById('arpl').value);


  if (isNaN(plar) == true) plar = 0;
  if (isNaN(srar) == true) srar = 0;
  if (isNaN(arpl) == true) arpl = 0;

  var res1 = plar * srar * arpl;

  document.getElementById('res1').innerHTML = plar * " * " * srar * " * " * arpl + " = " + res1;
}

function addi() {
  var zpsr = parseInt(document.getElementById('zpsr').value);
  var rbd = parseInt(document.getElementById('rbd').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(zpsr) == true) zpsr = 0;
  if (isNaN(rbd) == true) rbd = 0;
  if (isNaN(srar) == true) srar = 0;

  var res2 = zpsr * rbd * srar;

  document.getElementById('res2').innerHTML = zpsr * " * " * rbd * " * " * srar + " = " + res2;
}

function addit() {
  var znsm = parseInt(document.getElementById('znsm').value);
  var znst = parseInt(document.getElementById('znst').value);
  var colmr = parseInt(document.getElementById('colmr').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(znsm) == true) znsm = 0;
  if (isNaN(znst) == true) znst = 0;
  if (isNaN(colmr) == true) colmr = 0;
  if (isNaN(srar) == true) srar = 0;

  var res3 = znsm * 30 * 4 / 40 + znst * colmr * 30 * srar;

  document.getElementById('res3').innerHTML = znsm * " * " * 30 * " * " * 4 / "/" / 40 + "+" + znst * " * " * colmr * " * " * 30 * "*" * srar + " = " + res3;
}

function additi() {
  var znel = parseInt(document.getElementById('znel').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(znel) == true) znel = 0;
  if (isNaN(srar) == true) srar = 0;

  var res4 = 18 * 2 * znel * 30 * srar;

  document.getElementById('res4').innerHTML = 18 * " * " * 2 * " * " * znel * " * " * 30 * " * " * srar + " = " + res4;
}

function additio() {
  var znmr = parseInt(document.getElementById('znmr').value);
  var colmr = parseInt(document.getElementById('colmr').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(znmr) == true) znmr = 0;
  if (isNaN(colmr) == true) colmr = 0;
  if (isNaN(srar) == true) srar = 0;

  var res5 = znmr * colmr * 30 * srar;

  document.getElementById('res5').innerHTML = znmr * " * " * colmr * " * " * 30 * " * " * srar + " = " + res5;
}

function addition() {
  var res1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res1').value);
  var res2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res2').value);
  var res3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res3').value);


  if (isNaN(res1) == true) res1 = 0;
  if (isNaN(res2) == true) res2 = 0;
  if (isNaN(res3) == true) res3 = 0;

  var res6 = res1 + res2 + res3;

  document.getElementById('res6').innerHTML = res1 + " + " + res2 + " + " + res3 + " = " + res6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Программа сложения двух чисел</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h4>Cумма аренды</h4>
    <form>
      Площ.помещ. (м.кв.)<br><input id="plar" type="text" value="1"><br> Срок аренды фризера (мес)<br><input id="srar" type="text" value="1"><br> Аренд. Плата (за м.кв. в грн)<br><input id="arpl" type="text" value="1"><br> Зарплата 1 сотр. (грн.)<br>
      <input
        id="zpsr" type="text" value="1"><br>
        <input id="rbd" type="text" value="30" readonly hidden="hidden"><br> Цена сухой смеси/кг (грн)<br><input id="znsm" type="text" value="1"><br> Цена стаканчика (грн) <br><input id="znst" type="text" value="1"><br> Стоимость готового мороженого за
        порцию 75 гр (грн)<br><input id="znmr" type="text" value="1"><br> Количество продаж в день порций 75 гр. (шт)<br><input id="colmr" type="text" value="1"><br> Стоимость за Кват/час электроенерг. <br><input id="znel" type="text" value="1"><br>
    </form>
    <div id="res1"></div>
    <div id="res2"></div>
    <div id="res3"></div>
    <div id="res4"></div>
    <div id="res5"></div>
    <div id="res6"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
res5<br><input type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="additio();"><br> res2
<br><input type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="addi();"><br> res3
<br><input type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="addit();"><br> res1
<br><input type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="add();"><br> res4
<br><input type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="additi();"><br> res6
<br><input type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="addition();"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам, в строке document.getElementById('res1').innerHTML = , убрал вычисления , оставил только результат и все заработало

```js
function add() {
  var plar = parseInt(document.getElementById('plar').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);
  var arpl = parseInt(document.getElementById('arpl').value);


  if (isNaN(plar)==true) plar=0;
  if (isNaN(srar)==true) srar=0;
  if (isNaN(arpl)==true) arpl=0;

  var res1 = plar * srar * arpl;

  document.getElementById('res1').innerHTML = res1 ;
}
function addi() {
  var zpsr = parseInt(document.getElementById('zpsr').value);
  var rbd = parseInt(document.getElementById('rbd').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(zpsr)==true) zpsr=0;
  if (isNaN(rbd)==true)  rbd=0;
  if (isNaN(srar)==true) srar=0;

  var res2 = zpsr * rbd * srar;

  document.getElementById('res2').innerHTML = res2;
}
function addit() {
  var znsm = parseInt(document.getElementById('znsm').value);
  var znst = parseInt(document.getElementById('znst').value);
  var colmr = parseInt(document.getElementById('colmr').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(znsm)==true) znsm=0;
  if (isNaN(znst)==true) znst=0;
  if (isNaN(colmr)==true) colmr=0;
  if (isNaN(srar)==true) srar=0;

  var res3 = znsm * 30 * 4 / 40 + znst * colmr * 30 * srar;

  document.getElementById('res3').innerHTML = res3;
}
function additi() {
  var znel = parseInt(document.getElementById('znel').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(znel)==true) znel=0;
  if (isNaN(srar)==true) srar=0;

  var res4 = 18 * 2 * znel * 30 * srar;

  document.getElementById('res4').innerHTML = res4;
}
//Всего доходы
function additio() {
  var znmr = parseInt(document.getElementById('znmr').value);
  var colmr = parseInt(document.getElementById('colmr').value);
  var srar = parseInt(document.getElementById('srar').value);


  if (isNaN(znmr)==true) znmr=0;
  if (isNaN(colmr)==true) colmr=0;
  if (isNaN(srar)==true) srar=0;

  var res5 = znmr * colmr * 30 * srar;

  document.getElementById('res5').innerHTML = res5;
}
//
//Всего расходы
function addition() {
  var res1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res1').value);
  var res2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res2').value);
  var res3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res3').value);
  var res4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res4').value);


  if (isNaN(res1)==true) res1=0;
  if (isNaN(res2)==true) res2=0;
  if (isNaN(res3)==true) res3=0;
  if (isNaN(res4)==true) res4=0;

  var res6 = res1 + res2 + res3 + res4;

  document.getElementById('res6').innerHTML = res6;
}
//
//Прибыль
function additiont() {
  var res5 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res5').value);
  var res6 = parseInt(document.getElementById('res6').value);


  if (isNaN(res5)==true) res5=0;
  if (isNaN(res6)==true) res6=0;

  var res7 = res6 - res5;

  document.getElementById('res7').innerHTML = res7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Аренда фризера</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
    <h4>Калькулятор стоимости аренды фризера</h4>
  <form>
  <div class="col-d-4"> Площ.помещ. (м.кв.)<br><input id="plar" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
  <div class="col-d-4"> Срок аренды фризера (мес)<br><input id="srar" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  Аренд. Плата (за м.кв. в грн)<br><input id="arpl" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  Зарплата 1 сотр. (грн.)<br><input id="zpsr" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  <input id="rbd" type="text" value="30" readonly hidden="hidden"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  Цена сухой смеси/кг (грн)<br><input id="znsm" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  Цена стаканчика (грн) <br><input id="znst" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  Стоимость готового мороженого за порцию 75 гр (грн)<br><input id="znmr" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  Количество продаж в день порций 75 гр. (шт)<br><input id="colmr" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    <div class="col-d-4">  Стоимость за Кват/час электроенерг. <br><input id="znel" type="text" value="1"><br></div>
    </form>

  <output id="res1"></output>
  <output id="res2"></output>
  <output id="res3"></output>
  <output id="res4"></output>
  <output id="res5"></output>
  <output id="res6"></output>
  <output id="res7"></output>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
<div>
res1<br><input  type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="add();"><br>
res2<br><input  type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="addi();"><br>
res3<br><input  type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="addit();"><br>
res4<br><input  type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="additi();"><br>
res5<br><input  type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="additio();"><br>
res6<br><input  type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="addition();"><br>
res7<br><input  type="button" value="Просчитать" onclick="additiont();"><br>
</div>
```